# Write a switch statement with one case containing the other

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I would like to write a switch statement with three cases: `A`, `B` and `C`.
However, `C` is going to contain everything covered in `A` and then will add some other statements after that.

So if case `A` writes to a file, case `C` is supposed to write to a file and then write it to a table, too. How can we achieve this behavior without repeating the code for `A` in `C`?

Answer (score 6):

put A's code in a method and then call it from A and C and then add the extra code before the `break` of C

```
public void Foo (){}

switch(variable)
{
    case a: Foo(); break;
    case b: otherMethod(); break;
    case c: Foo(); ExtraWork(); break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative : C# have a [goto](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2.aspx) statement which might come in handy [Less codes]

```
        switch (CASE){
            case A:
              JUMP:
                // Code for A
                break;
            case B:
                // code for B
                break;
            case C:
                // Code for C
                goto JUMP; // Will jump to A 
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method for writing to file.

```
public void Write(){
  //your code here.
}
```

Now from switch statement case A and C call Write(). For case C after calling Write(), you can execute other codes.

Answer (score 1):

In your case I think about two options:

The first is having a distinct case for each value and extract the code in a private method that is called in both case:

```
switch (caseSwitch)
{
    case a:
        YourPrivateMethod();
        break;
    case b:
        // What ever you want to do
        break;
    case c:            
        YourPrivateMethod();
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Default case");
        break;
}

private void YourPrivateMethod()
{
   //some stuff
}
```

Second one is having a shared case for a and c :

```
switch (caseSwitch)
    {
        case a:
        case c:       
            // Do what A should

            if(caseSwitch == c)
            {
                // Do what C should
            }
            break;
        case b:
            // What ever you want to do
            break;     
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Default case");
            break;
    }
```

Regards.